# setting the end time of the end of a relationship in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have `Company` nodes that can have multiple relationships with `Address` nodes. These relationships have a `from_date` (date of beginning of the relationship) and I would like to set a `to_date` such that there are no relationships active at the same time.

I express the query like this:

```
MATCH (a1:Address)<-[allRels:LOCATED_AT]-(:Company)-[r:LOCATED_AT]->(a:Address)
WHERE r <> allRels AND r.from_date < allRels.from_date
WITH r, collect(allRels.from_date) as time
SET r.to_date = coalesce(min(time), date('9999-12-31'))
```

but I guess I am missing something as I am getting this error message:

```
Invalid use of aggregating function min(...) in this context (line 4, column 26 (offset: 203))
"SET r.to_date = coalesce(min(time), date('9999-12-31'))"
```

Can you please help me understand what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Aggregating functions like `MIN` and `COLLECT` can only be used in `WITH` or `RETURN` clauses. This query should fix your specific error:

```
MATCH (:Address)<-[allRels:LOCATED_AT]-(:Company)-[r:LOCATED_AT]->(:Address)
WHERE r.from_date < allRels.from_date
WITH r, MIN(allRels.from_date) AS min_time
SET r.to_date = coalesce(min_time, date('9999-12-31'))
```

However, I would actually assign appropriate `to_date` values this way:

```
MATCH (c:Company)-[rel:LOCATED_AT]->()
WITH c, rel ORDER BY rel.from_date
WITH c, COLLECT(rel) AS rels
FOREACH(i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(rels)-2) |
  SET rels[i].to_date = rels[i+1].from_date
)
```